# MySQL compare unix timestamps

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying to get all records which have a `date_created` within 2 hours ago. It's a unix timestamp which is created from the php function `time()`. Here is my current query:

```
SELECT id from gsapi_synsets where name = "Beyonce" and date_created BETWEEN  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_created) and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 hour))
```

Doesn't seem to be working though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If none of the `date_created` values will be in the future, you can use this:

```
SELECT id
FROM gsapi_synsets
WHERE name = 'Beyonce'
  AND date_created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR);
```

If `date_created` values can be in the future, use this, which cuts off at the current

```
SELECT id
FROM gsapi_synsets
WHERE name = 'Beyonce'
  AND date_created BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

Note that calling `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` without an argument returns the timestamp for "right now".

Comment: so by having my timestamp greater than the interval it infers that it is within the 2 hour window?

Comment: If you don't have future values for your time stamp, the "after two hours ago" query (the first one) work. If your timestamp can have values after NOW() you'll need to use the second query with the "between two hours ago and now". Hope that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get all row's between that row's datestamp and 2 hours from now, which won't work. Use this instead:

```
SELECT id from gsapi_synsets where name = "Beyonce" and date_created BETWEEN  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -2 hour)) and  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
```

Comment: I need it to go backwards 2 hours, not forwards. My fault, updated question